# kendo treeview mvc - error when clicking node

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, treeview

I'm getting an error within the kendo.all.min.js when I try and click on one of the nodes in a TreeView - anyone know if I have to further configure it to avoid this?

The error I'm getting is:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'set' of undefined or null reference
```

and the rough area that is highlighted on error by VS is:

```
return arguments.length?(n=e(n,r).closest(q),r.find(".k-state-selected").each(function(){var e=i.dataItem(this);e.set("selected",!1),delete e.selected}),n.length&&i.dataItem(n).set("selected",!0)...
```

What i'm after is basically a list of files within a parent folder, and if the file is active and has child files, then I'd like it to give it a URL so they can open the link, but if not, I'd like nothing to happen, but I don't want to completely disable the node as I'd like the user to be able to expand it or shrink it if required.

Here is the code I'm using for the treeview in MVC:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .Items(level1 =>
    {
        level1.Add().Text(rootFolderName)
        .SpriteCssClasses("folder")
        .Expanded(true)
        .Items(level2 =>
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var node in list)
            {
                string title = node.Title;
                string url = "";
                if (node.HasChildren)
                {
                    title = node.Title + "(" + node.ChildrenCount + ")";
                    url = "/Secure/Areas/Compliance.aspx?id=" + node.ItemId;
                }
                level2.Add().Text(title).Url(url)
                .Expanded(true);
            }
        });
    })
)
```

Anyone used these before and know what else I'm needing to do to achieve my aim?

Comment: If you do a view-source on the HTML page, could you post the JavaScript that gets generated?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, learning more as I go. Ended up using an event like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .Events(events => events
        .Select("onSelect")
        )
    .Items(level1 =>
```

and then added a `preventDefault` if the url is empty

```
function onSelect(e) {
        var dataItem = $('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.node);
        if (dataItem.href == 'undefined')
            e.preventDefault();
        else
            location.href = dataItem.href;
    }
```

There is maybe a better way, but this seems to work so I'm happy for now.